# How can I get live streaming audio which Android device below version 3.0?

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming

I used:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource(str_stream_url);
        // player.setDataSource("http://cdn.concreteloop.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Jennifer-Lopez-feat.-Pitbull-On-the-Floor.mp3");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
```

It's working in Android v4.0 but it is NOT working in Android 2.3.3..

What can I do??

Thx.

Comment: "Not working" _in what way_ ? Do you get any exception or other relevant errors in the logcat output?

Comment: The following errors I saw in Logcat:

02-06 13:08:29.440: E/MediaPlayer(2448): start called in state 4

02-06 13:08:29.440: E/MediaPlayer(2448): error (-38, 0)

02-06 13:08:29.460: E/MediaPlayer(2448): Error (-38,0)

Comment: `start called in state 4` means that you're calling `start` before `prepareAsync` has finished. You should use an [onPreparedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html) to receive a callback when the preparation is complete, and not call `start` before that.

Comment: player.setDataSource(this, myUri);
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.prepareAsync();
player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
player.setOnErrorListener(this);

is it OK?

Answer (score 1):

Also I tried this code in Android 2.3.3 but It didn't work.. At the end you can see the errors.

```
Uri myUri = Uri
            .parse("http://46.137.18.79:8000/;stream.nsv&type=mp3&autostart=true");

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        if (player == null) {
            this.player = new MediaPlayer();
        } else {
            player.stop();
            player.reset();
        }
        player.setDataSource(this, myUri); // Go to Initialized state
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.prepareAsync();

        Log.d(TAG, "LoadClip Done");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
    }
```

02-06 13:49:03.730: E/MediaPlayer(2718): stop called in state 1

02-06 13:49:03.730: E/MediaPlayer(2718): error (-38, 0)

02-06 13:49:03.730: D/MediaPlayer(2718): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

02-06 13:49:03.870: D/MyMain(2718): LoadClip Done

Thx.

Comment: I tried it in Android 4.0.3, it's working.. But in Android 2.3.3 or 2.1 or 2.2 etc.. It didn't work..